# R.java file regenerated and changed my constant values for RAW files

Tags: android, r.java-file

ok, I know I shouldn't have been doing this, but I'm having, in my published android application, some sounds stored in `RAW` folder.

When the user saves its work, a file will be created, with the sounds he choosed, containing the references: `R.raw.bass11` for example.

Now I'm doing an update and my application is not able to read anymore the `raw ids` in the files created in the previous version.

Checking deeply, I saw that in the old file it's trying to load for `R.raw.bass11 0x7f040000` but it doesn't find it as now in my `R.java` all the sounds start with `0x7f05` instead of `0x7f04`!

Of course I couldn't manually edit my R.java as it autogenerates itself again.

Anyone has any idea on how I can get my `R.java` file to reference my sounds `ID` back to the old values?

It's the 10 update I'm doing to my application in 2 years, and this never happened before!

Comment: just don't store the references to R ints  ... you can use name of the resource rom resource id or build own map with IDs like  hasmap with `{{id: 0, resid:R.raw.some1}, {id: 1, resid:R.raw.some2}, ...}` and store the id not resid ... but for now ... there is no possibilities(well, if you don't have DeLorean)... you have to use default sound and ask user to select it again (of course after you fix your code and stop storing R ints references

Comment: The problem is that is late already, as user already stored many files in this way and he can't re-choose the files. The only option now is to find a way to get my R.java file to reference the old values

Comment: the DeLorean is the only option ... good luck, and watch out for Biff

Comment: I don't have a DeLorean, but I have backup of my project. I tried to copy back the old R.java file but it get generated again, so it's not possible. There must be a way.

Comment: `aapt dump resources old.apk` build/generate a map from old values to new ... then fix an app and never store it again

Comment: about generating ... so dump will, well dump, something like this `resource 0x7f070021 com.example.myapp:raw/bass11: t=0x03 d=0x0000042c (s=0x0008 r=0x00)` ... now you need to build SparseIntArray ... like `SparseIntArray map = new SparseIntArray();` and for every line in dump generate something  like `map.put(0x7f070021 , R.raw.bass11)` (of course with right values) then you have to use it like `getSomeRawRes(map.get(obtainStoredId());`

Comment: Sorry I'm not following you. Which is your purpose with aapt?

Comment: but ... of course there would be a problem ... if someone use new version of the app the map would not help ... also as you said you are doing app 2 years ... so there is a chances that the problem could appear before but you didn't notice it ...

Comment: aapt dump resources old.apk <= would dump the resource ids with names for given apk ... so if you have old apk build  you can compare it with the new one ...